# Material "close" button in Toolbar instead of Back

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design

I have seen in Google's Inbox App, composing a new email, in the toolbar instead of the back button (an arrow) it has a "close" button (see picture).

How can I achieve this?

[image: inbox compose close button]

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use

```
this.getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action_close);
```

to achieve this.

You can create your own close icon or get from [material design icon set](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) on GitHub. Also, add this line before above line to make close function as the back arrow.

```
this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It doesn't replace the back arrow with the new icon, both appear. Furthermore, with this solution the icon doesn't get the "colorPrimaryDark" property.

Comment: It works but is not exactly what I wanted. I expected to work as back icon does, with "colorPrimaryDark". But it seems that "close" icon is not part of the SDK. Thanks @AlokNair!

Comment: Works fine when using ActionBarActivity and PARENT is specified in manifest. +1 for the answer. Thanks mate!

Comment: I found that I had to call setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled before SetHomeAsUpIndicator otherwise the icon would not be replaced.

Comment: and how to change back to the original?

Answer (score 25):

You need to define a parent in the manifest, then override **onSupportNavigationUp()** if using the support app bar of course.  Also, go to this handy site for the icon packs:  https://www.google.com/design/icons/

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.yourAwesomeLayout);

    setupToolBar();    
}

private void setupToolBar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    if (toolbar == null) return;

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close_white_24dp);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    finish(); // close this activity as oppose to navigating up

    return false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: any reason you returned false out of `onSupportNavigateUp()`? The documentation says its just a success flag

Answer (score 8):

sorry for late reply. **i found easiest solution for you**. here above all answer not works for me (`because i want to use toolbar not actionBar due to theming`). so try to add close button through xml layout. and it works.

**here is an xml syntax to add close button to toolbar(v7) .**

```
app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
```

ans here is an out put image [image: output image]

Comment: Where does `@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp` come from?

Comment: @CACuzcatlan That's just a random image he has in his drawable's folder. You can pick whatever icon.

Comment: @CACuzcatlan you can find it in Android Studio vector assets.

Answer (score 5):

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("Search");
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to defining the parent activity in the manifest is to handle what action to take in the onOptionsItemSelected method like in this example:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home/back button
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function

```
fun setNavigationIcon(@DrawableRes resId: Int? = null) {
        this.supportActionBar?.apply {
            setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
            setHomeAsUpIndicator(resId ?: R.drawable.ic_close)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

You can define a style:

```
<style name="Theme.Toolbar.Clear">
    <item name="toolbarNavigationIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha</item>
</style>
```

and use it in your theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Clear">
    <item name="toolbarTheme">@style/Theme.Toolbar.Clear</item>
</style>
```